# jquery find http elements in plain text and convert it to a link

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-selectors

I don't know if this is possible but I have a piece of plain text which always includes:

```
http://www.royalmail/portal/etc/etc/track.php?trackNumber=123345323
```

When dragged to my page from the database this obviously does not render as a link. Is there any way to select this piece of text (ie via the `http://`) and at the most basic wrap it with anchor tags - or more complexly - retrieve the address, wrap the address with anchor tags, and change the original `http://` text to something more understandable such as 'Track Parcel'

It should be noted that there could be numerous tracking references looped out at once.

My containing HTML is as follows

```
<div class="message_holder">
                <div class="mess_head" style="width:110px;">
                    <p><strong>Sender: </strong><? echo $row11['sender'];?></p>
                </div>
                <div class="mess_head" style="width:450px;">
                    <p><strong>Subject: </strong><span class="red"><? echo $row11['subject'];?></span></p>
                </div>
                <div class="mess_head" style="width:150px;">
                    <p><strong>Date Sent: </strong><? echo date('d/m/Y, H.ia', $row11['date_sent']);?></p>
                </div>
                <div class="mess_head" style="width:200px;">
                    <p><strong>Message ID: </strong><? echo $row11['message_id'];?></p>
                </div>
                <div class="mess_body">
                    <p><? echo html_entity_decode($row11['message']);?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The plain text links will all show up in the 'mess_body' class. I have tried using `html_entity_decode()` but this did not do the trick. If there is an easy way to do this via PHP rather than JQuery it could be simpler.

Comment: You should do this using PHP, not Javascript. Why can't you just do `<a href="<? echo html_entity_decode($row11['message']);?>">Track Parcel</a>`?

Comment: The link reference is contained within other plain text therefore it needs to be identified as a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it with PHP:

```
$text = preg_replace(
    '@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@', 
    '<a href="$1">$1</a>', /* or <a href="$1">Your TEXT</a> */
    $text
);
```

If I guess right, the url can be in your message, so your code should go like this:

```
<?php 
    echo 
     preg_replace(
        '@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@smi', 
        '<a href="$1">$1</a>',
        html_entity_decode($row11['message'])
     );
 ?>
```

Comment: This makes it simpler than using my jquery idea but I can't seem to get your example working in my code - will continue to mess with this - thanks

Comment: @Sideshow added an example for your code. Do you get any kind of error, or could you provide an example message which can be used as a test case?

Comment: The script runs fine - an example message is as follows:Tracking Number: BY281883295GB The above Royal Mail Tracking Number has been allocated for Appointment ID: 1357901511AeA It may take a couple of hours before the tracking number becomes live on the Royal Mail website. Follow the link below for Tracking details: http://track2.royalmail.com/portal/rm/track?trackNumber=11111111111